# Yii findAll() not working

Tags: php, yii, findall

I am new in `yii` framework. I'm trying to get all records by conditition from a table using model but every time I failed. I solved it by simple `mysqli1` query. But i want to get it `yii findAll();`. Below my i tried

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select('*');
$criteria->condition('u_id = $id');
$info = Info::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Thank all!

Comment: please attach logs or errors you have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`select('*')` should be `select = "*"` and `condition('u_id = $id')` should be `"u_id = $id"`. Try like below

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = '*';
$criteria->condition = "u_id = $id";
$info = Info::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my way to do it:

```
$id =10;
$info = Info::model()->findAll(array("u_id"=> $id ));
```

Comment: A code-only answer is almost never a good answer. Please edit it to explain what was wrong and how your code fixes it.